# How to install Gnumeric/ssconvert no Amazon Linux 2?

Tags: linux, amazon-linux, amazon-linux-2

I cannot find gnumeric/ssconvert package for Amazon Linux 2 (using yum).

I tried to compile the source code with error. Is there any easier way to install it?

**Compile Error**

```
[ec2-user@ip-172-31-6-34 gnumeric-1.12.55]$ ./configure --prefix=/usr
checking for a BSD-compatible install... /usr/bin/install -c
checking whether build environment is sane... yes
checking for a race-free mkdir -p... /usr/bin/mkdir -p
checking for gawk... gawk
checking whether make sets $(MAKE)... yes
checking whether make supports nested variables... yes
checking whether to enable maintainer-specific portions of Makefiles... yes
checking whether make supports nested variables... (cached) yes
checking for pkg-config... /usr/bin/pkg-config
checking pkg-config is at least version 0.9.0... yes
checking for gtk-doc... no
configure: WARNING:
  You will not be able to create source packages with 'make dist'
  because gtk-doc is not found.
checking for gtkdoc-check... no
checking for gtkdoc-check... no
checking for gtkdoc-rebase... no
checking for gtkdoc-mkpdf... no
checking whether to build gtk-doc documentation... no
checking for glib-2.0 >= 2.10.0 gobject-2.0  >= 2.10.0... no
checking whether NLS is requested... yes
./configure: line 4250: intltool-update: command not found
checking for intltool >= 0.35.0...  found
configure: error: Your intltool is too old.  You need intltool 0.35.0 or later.
[ec2-user@ip-172-31-6-34 gnumeric-1.12.55]$
```